# How to load previous ViewState when go back on previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to reload all my user changes when he want to go back on previous page and I tried to use `LoadViewState()` and `SaveViewState()` methods like this:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               if(Session["savedViewState"] != null)
                  {
                     Object saved = (Object)Session["savedViewState"];
                     LoadViewState(saved);
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                Session["savedViewState"] = SaveViewState();   
            }
        }
```

but it did't work. The session `savedViewState` is null. 
But I still do not know if these methods can solve the problem of reloading my all view state.

Comment: that is because. you are saving an empty viewstate into session. If its not a post back. it means its either a refresh or its a new load. in either case the viewstate is null. you are basically saving an empty view state everytime. you need to switch the code between the if else conditions

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch the code between the if else conditions

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



              if(Session["savedViewState"] != null && SaveViewState()!=null)
              {
                 Object saved = (Object)Session["savedViewState"];
                 LoadViewState(saved);
              }  
              else
              {
                  Session["savedViewState"] = SaveViewState();
              } 

    }
```

Comment: Now it even don't have a chance to save view state to session becasue there is no postback when I change something on my page.

Comment: When it's redirecting to second page data is not stored to session. So when I redirect back to this page `Session["savedViewState"]` is null.

Comment: You have overidden SaveViewState &  LoadViewState right? post that implementation

Comment: No, I did not do it.